# Instantiate a random class on program start

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, console-application

I'm just having a play around with inheritance and a few other concepts at the moment.

I have created a console app that amongst other things, holds the following classes:

```
Public abstract Organism

Public abstract Animal : Organism

Public Bird : Animal
Public Mammal : Animal
Public Reptile : Animal
Public Fish : Animal
Public Amphibian : Animal

Public Human : Organism
```

When the console app starts, I want to create a new object from either the Human, Fish, Mammal, Reptile, Bird or Amphibian class. Which one of these classes to instantiate is to be randomly chosen.

Once a class has been randomly chosen, I've used console.writeline to ask the user key questions to assign values to the given objects properties.

How do I create a random object from one of these classes?

Comment: do you mean to create an object from above mentioned class randomly by system..??

Comment: What you tried? Did you know about [Random Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// use the DLL of the project which is currently running
var runningAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssemby();

// all classes have a "Type" which exposes information about the class
var organismType = typeof(Organism);

// to keep track of all organism classes that we've found.
var allOrganismTypes = new List<Type>();

// go through all types in our project and locate those who inherit our 
// organism class
foreach (var type in runningAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (organismType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        allOrganismTypes.Add(type);
}

// Find a random index here (do it yourself)
var theRandomIndex = 10;


var selectedType = allOrganismTypes[theRandomIndex];

// activator is a class in .NET which can create new objects 
// with the help of a type
var selected = (Organism)Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType);
```

There are some "mistakes" in the code that you have to correct yourself.

Comment: Thanks jgauffin. I used yours as it was the least coupled to my code, giving me the option to add more species down the line with minimal amendments required.

Comment: Everybody loves LINQ... instead of the List declaration and the foreach: `List<Type> allOrganismTypes = runningAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => organismType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();`

Comment: Hmm, you also have to filter out the interface itself. `List<Type> allOrganismTypes = runningAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsInterface() && organismType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to choose types from a list, you could:

```
Type[] animals = new Type[]{ typeof(Bird), typeof(Mammal), typeof(Reptile), typeof(Fish), typeof(Amphibian) };
Animal animal = animals[new Random().Next(animals.Length)].GetConstructor(new Type[]{}).Invoke(new object[]{}) as Animal;
```

But for if you value simplicity/readability in your code (and you should), the following is much better if possible:

```
Animal animal = null;
switch (new Random().Next(5))
{
    case 0:
        animal = new Bird();
        break;
    case 1:
        animal = new Mammal();
...
}
```

Edit: I forgot about Activator.CreateInstance (simpler than the code I suggested), but using more basic code will be more readable if there aren't very many classes, and allows more flexibility (you don't need every type to have an even probability).

Answer (score 0):

Without using Reflection you can achieve it with a List of class Instances:

```
     var classlist = new List<Organism>();  
    classlist.Add(new Bird());
    classlist.Add(new Mammal());    
    classlist.Add(new Reptile());
    classlist.Add(new Fish());  
    classlist.Add(new Amphibian());
    classlist.Add(new Human());

    var r = new Random();

    var instance = classlist[r.Next(0,5)];
```

Comment: But now your already have instances. What if you only want to create the instance the moment you need it, without creating all the others?