# Passing arguments to Activator.CreateInstance<T>() depending on Class child

Tags: c#, .net

I'm learning C# on my own by down lots of weird stuffs and this day has been really difficult for me. In this third question (which I can't find an answer on any book, website or questions here in stackoverflow) may be the hardest one so far.

Right now I'm trying to create an Random Item Generator which will instantiate a random class from 3 possibles: `Weapon`, `Tool` and `Beverage`.

Now, I'm using the right answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437758/instantiate-a-random-class-on-program-start) question to generate an Item:

```
public void randomGenerate()
{
    var runningAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var itemType = typeof(Item);

    List<Type> allItemTypes = runningAssembly.GetTypes().Where
        (
            type => itemType.IsAssignableFrom(type)
        ).ToList();

    int randomIndex = RandomNumberGenerator.NumberBetween(0, allItemTypes.Count);

    var selectedType = allItemTypes[randomIndex];

    var selected = (Item)Activator.CreateInstance(selectedType);
}
```

But I would like to pass some arguments to the `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` depending on the class selected. If the random generator selects the `Weapon` class, it should pass an object filled with random properties such as: MinimumDamage, MaximumDamage, Material, Classification, Name, etc. If it is a `Beverage`, those args would be Name, Price and Flavor.

So, where can I store data like this:

```
List<string> namesList = new List<string>() { "Water", "Milk", "Tea", "Coffee", "Wine", "Juice" };
List<string> flavorsList = new List<string>() { "Cherry", "Strawberry", "Orange", "Lemon", "Pineapple", "Mango" };
```

and pass a random element from each list (within an object)?:

```
Object[] args = { nameIndex, flavorIndex };
```

Why those two arguments? Because they are necessary to create a `Beverage`:

```
class Beverage : item
{
    public string Flavor { get; set; }

    public Beverage
        (
            string name,
            string flavor
        ) : base(name)
    {
        Flavor = flavor;
    }
}
```

I know how to generate those random elements so the main two problems would be:

1) Store the list of properties somewhere so I can be able to find them.

2) Get those lists (depending on the class selected), generate an object that would store every required parameter (i know how to generate this object) and pass that object as the `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# 7 or higher you can use the "is" operator to know the type selected.
You can find the reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

As you know the type selected you can instantiate with different parameters.

With older versions of C# you can achieve this using "typeof"